# Projects like Stacks?

Tags: reference-request, big-list

I am interessted for other projects like Stacks Project which works on algebraic geometry.My questions are :

Are there other projects like that?
Are there projects like that which are not on research level,but rather introductory?
How to start a projects like that,aside from starting a wikibook?

Comment: does the nlab count?

Comment: Yeah sure,but nlab is more encyclopedic.I am more interessted in direction of Homotopy Type Theory.It is just fascinating how they made it work over GitHub

Comment: Not exactly introductory but (given your last comment) https://kerodon.net/ might be of interest to you. "It is modeled on the Stacks project, and is maintained by Jacob Lurie."

Answer (score 0):

On the same subject, from a [more detailed post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207388/pros-and-cons-of-stacks-project-as-a-reference-compared-with-ega-sga), there are the French projects EGA and [SGA](http://library.msri.org/books/sga/sga/index.html).